# Count distinct rows via a pair of known values

Tags: sql, join, distinct

I wasn't even sure how to phrase this question. I'll give example content and wanted output, I'm looking for a query to do this.

Let's say I have table called "flagged" with this content:

```
content_id | user_id
1          | 1
1          | 2
1          | 3
2          | 1
2          | 3
2          | 4
3          | 2
3          | 3
4          | 1
4          | 2
5          | 1
6          | 1
6          | 4
```

And I have a a-symmetrical relationship between content_ids:

```
master_content_id | slave_content_id
1                 | 2
3                 | 4
5                 | 6
```

For each "master" content_id (1, 3 and 5), I want to count how many distinct users have flagged either the master or the slave content, but count someone who flagged both as a single flag - which means that in the above example, content_id=1 was counted by user_id=1 (as content_id=1 and content_id=2), by user_id=2 (as content_id=1), by user_id=3 (as content_id=1 and content_id=2), and by user_id=4 (as content_id=2!)

An example of the output of the query I want to make is:

```
content_id | user_count
1          | 4          # users 1, 2, 3, 4
3          | 3          # users 1, 2, 3
5          | 2          # users 1, 4
```

I can't assume that the related content_ids are always a consecutive odd/even (i.e. 66 can be the master of the slave 58)

I am using MySQL and don't mind using its extensions to SQL (but rather the query be ANSI, or at least portable to the most databases)

Comment: There are some really great answers here. There are literally a million ways to do anything in SQL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the samples given, does this do the job (I don't have MySQL available to test)?

```
SELECT 
    ms.master_content_id,
    (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT f.user_id) FROM flagged f WHERE
                      f.content_id = ms.slave_content_id OR
                      f.content_id = ms.master_content_id)
FROM
    master_slave ms
```

It would be better *not* to have the DISTINCT, but I can't see a way around it.

Comment: I ended up using something very similar to this - Instead of an inner query, I did:
SELECT ms.master_content_id, COUNT(DISTINCT f.user_id)
FROM master_slave ms
JOIN flagged f ON f.content_id IN (ms.master_content_id, ms.Slave_content_id)
GROUP BY ms.master_content_id

Answer (score 3):

The query below worked for me.

I'm using a sub-query with a `UNION ALL` to treat your mapped contents equal to the direct contents.

```
SELECT master_content_id AS content_id,
       COUNT(DISTINCT user_id) AS user_count
FROM (
  SELECT master_content_id, slave_content_id
    FROM relationship
  UNION ALL
  SELECT master_content_id, master_content_id
    FROM relationship
) r
JOIN flagged f ON ( f.content_id = r.slave_content_id )
GROUP BY master_content_id
```

**Result:**

```
content_id  user_count
         1           4
         3           3
         5           2
```

Answer (score 2):

I think something like this will work for you (although `GROUP_CONCAT` is MySQL specific, similar concatenation can be achieved in other RDBMS)

```
SELECT  COALESCE(Master_Content_ID, Content_ID) AS Content_ID,
        COUNT(DISTINCT User_ID) AS Users,
        CONCAT('#Users ', GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT User_ID ORDER BY User_ID)) AS UserList
FROM    Flagged
        LEFT JOIN MasterContent
            ON Content_ID = Slave_Content_ID
GROUP BY COALESCE(Master_Content_ID, Content_ID)
```

Sample SQL Fiddle here: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d09be/2

Output:

```
CONTENT_ID  USERS   USERLIST
1           4       #Users 1,2,3,4
3           3       #Users 1,2,3
5           2       #Users 1,4
```

Comment: Didn't know about SQL Fiddle and about GROUP_CONCAT. I don't actually need the userlist, that was just a comment, but it's still good to learn something new :)

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT master_content_id      AS content_id
     , COUNT(*)               AS user_count
     , GROUP_CONCAT(user_id)  AS flagging_users
FROM 
  ( SELECT r.master_content_id 
         , f.user_id
    FROM relationship AS r
      JOIN flagged AS f
        ON f.content_id = r.master_content_id
  UNION 
    SELECT r.master_content_id
         , f.user_id
    FROM relationship AS r
      JOIN flagged AS f
        ON f.content_id = r.slave_content_id
  ) AS un
GROUP BY master_content_id
```